# Upvote undo bug? (Chrome 28.0.1500.71 on OS X 10.8.4)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment-voting

I just upvoted a comment and was immediately greeted by this alert:

> Are you sure you want do undo your upvote on this comment? You will not be able to upvote it again.

When I clicked OK the comment was **not** upvoted and I could not upvote it anymore.

This behavior seems to be a bug.

Using Google Chrome 28.0.1500.71 on OS X 10.8.4 with an Apple Magic Trackpad.

**Edit**: This seems to be intermittent. It happens about every three or four times. I could reproduce it at least three times. I could not reproduce it by double-clicking. I don't have problems with accidental double-clicking elsewhere, even on Windows I remote desktop to.

Comment: Writing a comment for others to try and reproduce this issue on - because you've tried more than once, right? =)

Comment: @J.Steen, +1 to you, can't reproduce ;)

Comment: No repro on 28.0.1500.72 at least. You're sure you didn't accidentally click twice?

Comment: Yeah, no repro, same versions (browser and OS both).

Comment: Perhaps it's intermittent. It happened to me twice. Now it happened to me a third time. It could be that my Apple Magic Trackpad is slightly prone to double clicking, I agree. But I never had a problem with it except this upvote undo thing on SO.

Comment: You could possibly try and look at the developertools and check if you can see the websocket calls for upvote/unupvote. Dunno if that'd actually help, though.

Comment: Reproduced only if I double-click.

Comment: @CodyGray I could not reproduce it by double-clicking.

Comment: couldn't reproduce either

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you might clicked the comment upvote button twice accidently.

Then only it will ask for permission to undo the upvote. Once you undo the upvote, you are not permitted to vote again on that comment.

Please check, *is there any [problem](http://www.instructables.com/id/Repair-mouse-with-double-click-problem/) with your mouse?*

Comment: It happened twice. Maybe I could have clicked the button twice but not twice in a row! :-)

Comment: I don't think that I have a real problem with the trackpad. Because if I would accidentally double-click the whole time I would have problems elsewhere.

Comment: @nalply, so it happened accidentally :)

Comment: I could reproduce this behavior a third time. It happens at about every three times.

Comment: @nalply, check with a mouse instead of trackpad

Comment: Downvote from me because do not treat me like this: «Did you connect your system to power?»

Comment: @nalply, the issue can't be reproduced by anyone, that's y I suggest the mouse than trackpad, I'm using OSX 10.8.4, chrome 28.0.1500.71,safari 6.0.4 (8536.29.13)

Comment: I do know that my bug report could be bogus. However I could reproduce it more than one time. My trackpad is working fine. So I report and the developers decide. **I have spoken my mind.** :-)

Comment: @nalply Azik is just trying to **help you** narrow down the problem. Without really specific details the developers can't and won't do anything anyway.

Comment: Do you have touch-to-click enabled as well as the actual click?  If so then it's very possible to get the occasional doubleclick, certainly happened to me sometimes when I hadn't disabled that yet.

Comment: @Joe, sssh.. don't treat others like "Did you connect your system to power?" the issue is different :)